# How to stream CloudWatch log group to specific Lambda function version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda

When creating a new subscription filter for a CloudWatch log group, the AWS Console doesn't seem to offer a way to select a specific Lambda fn version. This is important for CI/CD where I might want to update the fn and test it without breaking current subscriptions.

Is there a way to lock the fn version for a subscription? If so then how do you achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2020-10-19**

You must also grant CloudWatch logs [permission to invoke your lambda function](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html)!

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name "foo" \
--qualifier "56" \
--statement-id "Allow-invoke-foo-or-whatever" \
--principal "logs.us-east-42.amazonaws.com" \
--action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
--source-arn "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/ecs/my-prod-server:*" \
--source-account "123456789012"
```

---

**Original answer**

Still not sure if possible via console but I've found a solution using [aws-cli](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/put-subscription-filter.html). You can add version number at the end of the destination arn. For example, to send logs to `foo` version `56`, do:

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter \
--log-group-name "/ecs/my-prod-server" \
--filter-name "BestFilter_ever" \
--filter-pattern "{$.level=*}" \
--destination-arn "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-42:123456789012:function:foo:56"
```

Comment: use alias should be better

Comment: Great idea, @Kane! Thanks.